# How can I get the average of two different columns in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new in linq and a bit confused regarding the aggregate things. In the following I need to take the average of `m_corected_av` and `m_wind_speed`. Can you please give me a hint?

```
  var ChartDetails = (from c in db.StatisticsMonthlies
                            join d in db.MasterDatas
                            on c.m_turbine_id equals d.m_turbine_id
                            join s in db.UsersTurbines
                            on d.turbine_id equals s.tur_id
                            where c.m_date > lastyeardate && s.user_id == useID
                            select new MonthlyDailyStatsOfTurbines
                            {
                                m_energy_prod = (int)c.m_energy_prod,
                                turbine_name = d.turbine_name,
                                m_wind_speed = Math.Round((Decimal) c.m_wind_speed),
                                m_wind_speed = (int)c.m_wind_speed,
                                m_date = c.m_date,                                  
                                m_corrected_av = c.m_corrected_av,

                            }).ToList().OrderBy(m => m.m_date).Select(o => new MonthlyDailyStatsOfTurbines
                            {
                                m_energy_prod = (int)o.m_energy_prod,
                                turbine_name = o.turbine_name,
                                //m_wind_speed = Math.Round((Decimal) c.m_wind_speed),
                                m_wind_speed = (int)o.m_wind_speed,
                                m_date = o.m_date,
                                m_data_completeness = o.m_data_completeness,
                                m_corrected_av = o.m_corrected_av,
                                date_test = o.m_date.ToString("MMMM yyyy")

                            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be understood in different ways. If you want bot the average of the av's in the list and the average windspeed, you can go for sth. like:

```
var avg_corrected_av = ChartDetails.Average(x => x.m_corected_av); 
var avg_wind_speed = ChartDetails.Average(x => x.m_wind_speed);
```

if you want a list of the averages of the av's and windspeeds of each item in your result set, you could do:

```
var avg = ChartDetails.Select(x => (x.m_corected_av + x.m_wind_speed)/2);
```

Comment: where should I use the group by?

Comment: wouldn't make sense, because you already converted to list, the database query has already been executed.

Comment: what you say is correct,but I have to the average outside of my query,m_corrected_av.Add(ChartDetails.Where(p => p.m_date.Month == i).Average(p => p.m_corrected_av))  like this,what if I want to take the average inside of my"chartdetail" ?

Comment: if you need all the data you are querying, i don't see any benefit. It may only make your (already complex) query more complicated, won't it?